# Sharepoint 2010 Hide User permission options in News site menu

Tags: permissions, site

Has only tried hiding

The permissions section on new site in sharepoint 2010.

Permissions
You can give permission to access your new site to the same users who have access to this parent site, or you can give permission to a unique set of users.

I do not want users to select unique permissions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If want a no - code solution, you will have to modify the newsbweb.aspx application page.
Be warned this will affect all the web applications.

- Go to the 14 hive Template\Layouts directory.
- Save a copy of the newsbweb.aspx file as a backup for when you want to revert
- Open the file for editing.
- add a registration line at top

  <%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="InputFormSection2" src="~/_controltemplates/InputFormSection2.ascx" %>
- Locate the InputFormSection tag which shows the web permissions options to users
  This usually be at line 190 or 191

  <wssuc:InputFormSection   runat="server"
  title="<%$Resources:wss,newsbweb_idInputTitleContent%>"
  Description="<%$Resources:wss,newsbweb_idInputDescriptionContent%>"
  id="idPermSection"
  >
  <Template_InputFormControls  >
      <wssuc:InputFormControl  LabelText="<%$Resources:wss,**newsbweb_idInputLabelPermissions**%>"
- Change the start and end tags to **wssuc:InputFormSection2**
- Save the file.
- Now go to the 14 hive Template\ControlTemplates directory
- Select the InputFormSection.ascx file and create a copy - name it InputFormSection2.ascx
- Open InputFormSection2.ascx for editing
- Put style="display:none" in the two main tr tags in the file (lines 9 and 35)

That's all users will not see the permissions option while creating subsite.
Also the subsites created will inherit parent site's permission  as that is the default behaviour.